# Trouble using Android simple file chooser

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm trying to use the simple file chooser available here:
https://rogerkeays.com/simple-android-file-chooser

Struggling to get it to work, I call in my main activity:

```
new FileChooser(myactivity.this).setFileListener(new FileSelectedListener() {
@Override public void fileSelected(final File file) {
    // do something with the file
}).showDialog();
```

I've added the class and referenced it - and it compiles OK - however it crashes with:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with this?

Many Thanks

EDIT: Full logcat

```
12-13 13:35:05.995 11029-11029/com.test.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.test.project, PID: 11029
                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120) 
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                    at com.test.project.FileChooser.refresh(FileChooser.java:103)
                                                                    at com.test.project.FileChooser.<init>(FileChooser.java:62)
                                                                    at com.test.project.myactivity.onToggleClickedPlayback(myactivity.java:1200)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120) 
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

12-13

Comment: post your whole logcat error

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - was because the filesystem was empty on the emulator, works fine on a real device - will tweak the code to handle !